# Firebase function: cannot read property 'userId' of undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

im trying to send an email through sendgrid via. a firestore trigger. I just cant seem to get the userId out from my context. Any suggestions?
 [Image link to error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9gub.png)

```js
exports.firestoreEmail = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{userId}')
  .onCreate((context) => {
    const userId = context.params.userId;
    const db = admin.firestore();

    return db
      .collection("users")
      .doc(userId)
      .get()
      .then((doc) => {
        const user = doc.data();
        const msg = {
          to: user.email,
          from: "<myEmail>",
          subject: "New Follower",

          // custom templates
          templateId: "d-1584af76f10d475d8cc99d28e5501cf9",
          substitutionWrappers: ["{{", "}}"],
           substitutions :{
               name: user.displayName
           }
        };
        return sgMail.send(msg);
      })
      .then(() => console.log("email sent!"))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`context` should be the second parameter to your function.  It doesn't matter that you named it "context" - the position matters entirely.  The first argument is a DocumentSnapshot of the new document, so you'll have to give it name as the first parameter, even if you don't use it:

```
exports.firestoreEmail = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{userId}')
  .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    const userId = context.params.userId;
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, if you found an answer helpful, it's customary to upvote it and mark the answer as correct using the buttons on the left.